# Compiling GNU assembler to windows

Tags: c++, c, assembly, x86-64, calling-convention

I need to compile assembly file that is written in GNU assembler in windows.
The file is compiled correctly in Linux using as assembler.
The assembly file contains a global deceleration of function that receives 2 params, which should be called from C/C++ visual studio 2013.

How can I do that ?

Here are part of .s file:

```
.globl func
func:
pushq %rbp
pushq %r12
pushq %r15
pushq %r13
pushq %r14
subq $40,%rsp

movq %rdi,%rbp //the first param
movq %rsi,%r12 //the second param

//real code starts here...


//restore stack and return

addq $40,%rsp
popq %r14
popq %r13
popq %r15
popq %r12
popq %rbp
ret
```

Thanks all !

Comment: I'm not so sure you can count on compatible ABI's for this stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft calling convention differs from the sysv abi that pretty much the rest of the world uses. If the code that you omitted from the question is self-contained, you basically only need to worry about argument passing and preserving registers.

Luckily, to access the arguments you just have to replace the two registers `rdi` and `rsi` with `rcx` and `rdx`, respectively.

As for saving registers, the code is presumably not modifying `rbx` as that needs to be preserved and there is no matching `push`. Additionally, both conventions preserve `r12` through `r15` so we don't need to worry about those. Microsoft convention however also mandates `rdi` and `rsi` be preserved, which are used for arguments under the sysv abi and are otherwise considered volatile. Thus, you need to add a `push`/`pop` pair for those.

You didn't mention whether the function body uses any SIMD or FPU things, so I am not going to cover those. Also, I assume your function is returning `void`.

As such, the modified assembly could look like:

```
.globl func
func:
pushq %rbp
pushq %r12
pushq %r15
pushq %r13
pushq %r14
pushq %rdi
pushq %rsi
subq $40,%rsp

movq %rcx,%rbp //the first param
movq %rdx,%r12 //the second param

//real code starts here...


//restore stack and return

addq $40,%rsp
popq %rsi
popq %rdi
popq %r14
popq %r13
popq %r15
popq %r12
popq %rbp
ret
```

On the C side, you just need to declare it as `extern void func(int a, int b)` or equivalent. When calling from c++, you should use `extern "C"`.